# Are comparisons between a human and an animal considered vulgar or obscene in standard English?

Tags: meaning-in-context, culture

In my mother tongue, drawing an analogy between a human and an animal such as a dog, goat, donkey, monkey, or fox is offensive and taboo. Is this true in English?

For example:

> He is as tired as a dog.

or

> What is after you? You are as jumpy as a goat!

Do these convey any insult or vulgarity?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context, and the animal.

Your first example is actually really close to a common (and *not* offensive) phrase:

> I'm dog-tired!

This simply means you're really tired, and would be not at all offensive.

Here are a few other examples of idiomatic, inoffensive animal comparisons:

> He's got bat ears! (He has very good hearing.)
>
> She's got hawk eyes! (She has very good eyesight.)
>
> He's as sneaky as a fox! (I suppose this one depends on context; whether or not "sneakiness" is good or bad in this case. It could go either way.)

Here are some examples where animal comparisons can be offensive, or at least have a negative connotation:

> He's nothing but a rat! (He's a liar, traitor, sneak, rotten person.)
>
> You're as dirty as a pig! (Self-explanatory.)

So it really just depends. A comparison to an animal is not offensive in and of itself. But sometimes it can be.

Comment: What about *as jumpy as a goat*?

Comment: No, "You're as jumpy as a goat" would not be offensive. It's as innocuous as "You seem nervous."

Answer (score 1):

In English, this generally isn't an issue -- similes comparing people to animals are common and generally not considered vulgar or offensive, so you should be okay using them. The only one I can think of where this isn't the case is calling someone a "**bitch.**"

A bitch literally is a female dog, but it's rarely ever used in any context other than insults because its meaning has been co-opted to mean "a disagreeable/argumentative/rude/cowardly/generally unpleasant person." It is used to describe people of either gender, although the exact meaning can vary based on the gender of the person it is being used to describe. For example:

- Calling a woman a bitch generally implies that she is assertive in a way that makes the speaker uncomfortable.
- Calling a man a bitch generally implies that he is a coward or complainer.
- Alternately, one can use the word as a verb ("Quit your bitching"), in which case it means "to complain." As a verb, the meaning is less dependent on gender.

Once again, this is vulgar and almost exclusively considered a swear word when used, but this is the only example of comparing people to animals that is negative that I can think of.